# TypeError: com.telerik.widget.gauge.RadRadialGaugeView is not a constructor

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have been trying to implement the basic gauge function as said in NativeScript UI's [getting started guide](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/Gauges/getting-started). But I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: com.telerik.widget.gauge.RadRadialView is not a constructor`.

Package.json:

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.ngModel",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "3.5.0-rc-2018.1.8.1"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
        "allow-publish": "^1.0.4",
        "nativescript-angular": "~5.1.0",
        "nativescript-pro-ui": "^3.3.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~5.5.2",
        "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
        "babel-types": "6.4.5",
        "babylon": "6.4.5",
        "lazy": "1.0.11",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.6.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
    }
}
```

The HTML and the component code is same as the in the getting started guide.

Comment: Did you Import the `NativeScriptUIGaugesModule` to your app's `ngModule`, like described in the [prerequisites](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/getting-started) of the guide? Note: in the example code of the ngModule the component is commented out.

Comment: Yes I did. I imported the same.

Comment: Ok, can you provide your `@NgModule` declared component? And, if existing, the component where the error appears?
I am not 100% sure, but I think the problem could be the naming because the error describes a `RadRadialView` which seems not to exist but a [`RadRadialGauge`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radradialgauge.html) does.

Answer (score 2):

try `tns platform remove android` and then `tns run android`.
or 
`tns platform remove ios` and then `tns run ios`.

make sure after adding `nativescript-ui` component plugin you remove and re-add working platform. not doing this causes many issues sometimes.

Comment: That's true, my Telerik AutoComplete and DataForm NativeScript components were not working on Android before I re-added platform. After that, everything was fine.